# I have a list of objects with time and unit. ONe object can be of 10 DAYS other can be one 1 WEEK how do i sort in this case?

Tags: python

```
[{'time':10,'unit':'DAYS'},{'time':1, 'unit':'WEEKS'}]
```

How do I sort them based on which is smaller in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def _sort_on_time(item):
    if item["unit"] == "WEEKS":
        # Convert to days.
        time_val = item["time"] * 7
    elif item["unit"] == "DAYS":
        time_val = item["time"]
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unable to determine the unit: %s" % item["unit"])
    return time_val
sorted([{'time':10,'unit':'DAYS'},{'time':1,'unit':'WEEKS'}], key=_sort_on_time)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the line `time_val = 0`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think it's meant to be a fallback value for unknown units.

Comment: @timgeb Yes, that's probably that... But then, raising an exception would be better.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Agreed. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you this solved problem in real simple way